# How to remove an item from a nested ConcurrentDictionary?

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

What I'm trying to do is to keep online members of group chats in memory. I've defined a static nested dictionary like this:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChatMember>> onlineGroupsMembers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChatMember>>();
```

Then when a new member arrives, I add it:

```
        onlineGroupsMembers.AddOrUpdate
            (chatKey,
            (k) => // add new
            {
                var dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChatMember>();
                dic[chatMember.Id] = chatMember;
                return dic;
            },
            (k, value) => // update
            {
                value[chatMember.Id] = chatMember;
                return value;
            });
```

Now the problem is how can I delete a member from the inner dictionary? also how to delete a dictionary from outer dictionary when it's empty?

Concurrent dictionary has [TryRemove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryremove?view=netframework-4.7.2) but it does not help and checking for [ContainsKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.containskey?view=netframework-4.7.2) then removing it is not atomic.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code that calls `TryRemove()`?

Comment: @BACON It's not even possible. it gets a `key` which in my case is group key, and removes the value which is a dictionary of that group members. I just want to remove a single member, not all.

Comment: Perhaps a nested concurrent dictionary isn't the best way to go? Either way, it seems that you need a `TryGetValue` to extract the inner dictionary, and then a `TryRemove` on the inner dictionary.

Comment: @John Thanks. and for the second part, is it possible to safely remove an inner dictionary if it's empty?

Comment: How are you retrieving members from the inner dictionary?  It's similar to that.  You pass the group ID to the outer dictionary to get the inner dictionary, and then pass the member ID to that to remove that user.  `var groupDictionary = onlineGroupsMembers["groupID"]; var wasRemoved = groupDictionary.TryRemove("memberID", out ChatMember member);`

Comment: @John do you suggest another way other than concurrent dictionary? I've already a mongoDb database, but I want to keep it in memory for performance.

Comment: @BACON Thanks .. please write it so I can choose it as answer.. (for half part of it though) :)

Comment: Couldn't you accomplish this with two dictionaries that aren't nested?  One that maps from groups to either `ChatMember`s or member IDs, and another that maps from member IDs to `ChatMember`s.

Comment: @BACON That's probably the best suggestion.

Comment: @BACON That way can I get a list of a specific group's members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a `ChatMember` from a group you need to get the `ConcurrentDictionary<>` for that group with...

```
var groupDictionary = onlineGroupsMembers["groupID"];
```

...or...

```
var groupDictionary = onlineGroupsMembers.TryGetValue("groupID", out ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChatMember> group);
```

From `groupDictionary` you would then attempt to remove the member...

```
var wasMemberRemoved = groupDictionary.TryRemove("memberID", out ChatMember removedMember);
```

To completely remove a group from `onlineGroupsMembers` you would call `TryRemove` directly on that dictionary...

```
 var wasGroupRemoved = onlineGroupsMembers.TryRemove("groupID", out ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChatMember> removedGroup);
```

A less cumbersome way to implement this might be with two dictionaries that are not nested.  One would map from a group ID to something like a [`ConcurrentBag<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1) or a concurrent [`HashSet<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) (if it existed) of its `ChatMember`s...

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<ChatMember>> groupIdToMembers;
```

...or from a group ID to its member IDs...

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentBag<string>> groupIdToMemberIds;
```

Note that `ConcurrentBag<>` allows duplicate values.

In the latter case, if you want a quick way to get the `ChatMember` for a given member ID, you could use another dictionary for that...

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChatMember> memberIdToMember;
```

Comment: Thanks.. I want to remove a group only if it's empty though.

Comment: Ahh, maybe after removing it, check the removed object again to see if it has got some values meanwhile, and add them back!

Comment: Ah, yes.  The `TValue` of the group dictionary needs to be a collection type, or otherwise some kind of `ChatGroup` type that contains a collection of `ChatMember`s.  That's the tricky part with wanting to remove the group when the last member leaves is ensuring there's not a race condition between removing the group and a new member joining; you can't check the `Count` of the nested dictionary and then remove it from `onlineGroupsMembers` atomically.

Comment: using ConcurrentBag is still nested, and this approach adds a second list that should take care of and keep them synced. Thanks for your answer. maybe I should forget about the dictionaries..